# 7-segment display communication

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, decoder, quartus

[image]

[image]

I have attempted to solve this problem  making kmaps for the binary counter, mux and decoder however I'm getting stuck on the making them all talk to each other bit, I am using a ATmega32L and a EPM7032A board. Ignore the Atmel ATF2500C board that is listed. Program used for coding the microcontroller is AVR studio and the logic device is coded on Quartus.

If someone could even give me a point in the right direction of how to make them talk to each other that would be great.

**EDIT***
[image]
[image]
[image]
here is what i have so far
[image]
[image]

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is for you to come up with a solution. Make a list of what you do know and what you don’t know. Then work to answer what you don’t know. Simply put, break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: thanks mate. problem is solved in the sense i know how to make each part work but i have no clue where to start to assemble the puzzle.

Comment: Then show us what you know.  Homework with no attempt at a solution is locked.  Start with your kmaps and add whatever you think is relevant.  Easier for us to connect the pieces, mate!

Comment: Thanks @StainlessSteelRat i have edited my post now. i guess the simpliest question to answer at this point is what am i doing in AVR to make these programs ive written in quartus talk to each other?

Comment: If D0-D3 is supposed to be Q0-Q3, then you have interpreted your kmaps incorrectly.  Your Q0 and Q3 are incorrect. Both should be two terms.  Q1 & Q2 good.

Comment: "what am i doing in AVR to make these programs ive written in quartus talk to each other?" Please start a new question and ask _that_ question, then.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat thanks for that ill fix that up.

Comment: @DavideAndrea that was the point of THIS post not to help answer the whole homework question as such.